# concatenate values of rows for which index is in a nested list

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe, data-cleaning, data-conversion

I have TWO list of indexes as
continuous = [[2, 3, 4], [10, 11]] (tuples can be length 3 or 4 or 5 or more)
and non-continuous = [[7], [56]] (tuples can be length = 1)
and a data frame as under:

```
INDEX        PARTICULARS
2             COMPENSATION CHARGE USE OF
3                   WAREHOUSING PREMISES
4                            FOR APR 22.
7                        RENT FOR APR 22
10                      BEING PAYMENT OF
11                   RENT OF NEW BRANCH.
56                    TOWARDS LANDSCAPE.
```

I need to concatenate the data frame as under:

```
PARTICULARS

COMPENSATION CHARGE USE OF WAREHOUSING PREMISES FOR APR 22   (being [2,3,4]
RENT FOR APR 22                                              (being[7] 
BEING PAYMENT OF RENT OF NEW BRANCH.                         (being[10,11]
TOWARDS LANDSCAPE.                                           (being [56]
```

Comment: what you have in index is list of list... not tuples...

Answer (score 0):

Are you looking for something like this below;

```
import pandas as pd
df = pd.DataFrame({"INDEX":[2,3,4,7,10,11,56],
                   "PARTICULARS":["COMPENSATION CHARGE USE OF","WAREHOUSING PREMISES","FOR APR 22.","RENT FOR APR 22","BEING PAYMENT OF","RENT OF NEW BRANCH.","TOWARDS LANDSCAPE."]})

continuous = [[2, 3, 4], [10, 11]]
non_continuous = [[7], [56]]
lst = continuous + non_continuous
INDEX,group = [],[]
for i,item in enumerate(lst):
    INDEX = INDEX + item
    group = group + [i]*len(item)
df1 = pd.DataFrame({"INDEX":INDEX,"Group":group})

df = df.merge(df1,on="INDEX",how="left")
    df2 = pd.DataFrame(df.groupby(["Group"])["PARTICULARS"].apply(lambda x: "%s" % ', '.join(x)))

# Output of df2

                                             PARTICULARS
Group                                                   
0      COMPENSATION CHARGE USE OF, WAREHOUSING PREMISES, FOR APR 22.
1                              BEING PAYMENT OF, RENT OF NEW BRANCH.
2                                                    RENT FOR APR 22
3                                                  TOWARDS LANDSCAPE.
```

Answer (score 0):

Lets say your existing dataframe is `df`, then create a dataframe called `df_lists` with your two lists `continuous_lists` and `non_continuous_lists`. Then merge them and group by `grp` column in `df_lists` and agg the `PARTICULARS`. See below code.

```
continuous_lists = [[2, 3, 4], [10, 11]]
non_continuous_lists = [[7], [56]]
df_lists = pd.DataFrame({'INDEX': 
                         [*continuous_lists, *non_continuous_lists]}).rename_axis('grp')
df_lists = df_lists.explode('INDEX').reset_index()

out = df_lists.merge(df).groupby('grp')['PARTICULARS'].agg(' '.join).reset_index(drop=True)
```

print(out):

```
0    COMPENSATION CHARGE USE OF WAREHOUSING PREMISE...
1                 BEING PAYMENT OF RENT OF NEW BRANCH.
2                                      RENT FOR APR 22
3                                   TOWARDS LANDSCAPE.
```

Answer (score 0):

You can craft a dictionary to [`map`](https://pandas.pydata.org/docs/reference/api/pandas.Series.map.html) for [`groupby.agg`](https://pandas.pydata.org/docs/reference/api/pandas.core.groupby.DataFrameGroupBy.aggregate.html):

```
group = {k:v for v,l in enumerate(continuous+non_continuous) for k in l}
# {2: 0, 3: 0, 4: 0, 10: 1, 11: 1, 7: 2, 56: 3}

out = (df
  .groupby(df['INDEX'].map(group))
  ['PARTICULARS'].agg(' '.join)
  .to_frame()
)
```

Output:

```
                                             PARTICULARS
INDEX                                                   
0      COMPENSATION CHARGE USE OF WAREHOUSING PREMISE...
1                   BEING PAYMENT OF RENT OF NEW BRANCH.
2                                        RENT FOR APR 22
3                                     TOWARDS LANDSCAPE.
```